# Video in Fusion Tables info window gets truncated or doesn't show

Tags: youtube, google-fusion-tables

I added YouTube videos to a column using the old embed code and setting the column to 8-line image.

When I embed my map in another site, the videos don't show at all or get severely truncated, as [this image shows](https://fusion-tables-users-group.googlegroups.com/attach/dc3995e2e8e85563/FT-video.jpg?view=1&part=4).

Sometimes when viewing the map in FT itself, a white square shows up above the video window. When I pan the map around with the info box open, that white square remains in place, obscuring the video.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the 8-line image format is causing the problem. Try removing this format, keeping the column Type Text and Format set to None.